# How to draw the line that triggered the trigger pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

This is my code:

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE  TRIGGER TR_DEL
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON DIZIONARIO_CHIAVI_DA_ESCLUDERE
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_cursore_prendi_riga IS 
       SELECT CURRICULUM_CHIAVE_RICERCA 
         FROM PERSONA; 
    myCursor PERSONA.CURRICULUM_CHIAVE_RICERCA%TYPE; 
BEGIN
  OPEN c_cursore_prendi_riga;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_cursore_prendi_riga INTO myCursor;
    EXIT WHEN c_cursore_prendi_riga%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line('oo='|| myCursor );

    -- Here I need it      

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_cursore_prendi_riga;
END;
```

I need the row that started the trigger, thanks

Comment: You reference a column/columns of a row that fires a trigger using `:new` or `:old` pseudo record. For example `:new.col_name`.

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nicholas Krasnov is right, to put this in an answer:

:new and :old are used as pseudo-records. Documentation is here:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG50000

and here the explanation of these pseudo-records:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS99955

Most important: pseudo-records can not used like "normal" records. You have to name each column...

For example you can not use:

```
my_special_function(:new);
```

You wil have to create a "real" record:

```
declare
  myrec  mytable%rowtype;
begin
  myrec.id := :new.id;
  myrec.name := :new.name;
  myrec.birthdate := :new.birthdate;
  etc etc etc
  my_special_function(myrec);
end
```